# When is service class initialized?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, proxy-classes, channelfactory

If I've created a service reference using visual studio, and the following client was generated:

```
public partial class MyServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<MyType>
```

The question is: when is the **service** class being initialized? (when is "new MyService()" called)
When I do this:

```
MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
```

or perhaps only here:

`client.DoStuff()`?

(The reason I'm asking is because I want to know how long the service object is still alive before being garbage collected)

Comment: Which service object? The server side or local client proxy?

Comment: @toadflakz - the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the binding I think. For the common bindings (SOAP and NetTcp) the client does not use the network at all until the first call is made. This implies that the server object is not instantiated before that because the server is not notified.

It is usually best to use `PerCall` instancing and have the service object be really cheap. That way you do not need to think about this issue at all and you don't even need the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

The server-side instancing behaviour is controlled by the `InstanceContextMode` enumeration which you specify as part of your `ServiceContract`.

The behaviour of each option is as follows:

- PerCall - Instance is created for the lifetime of a call to the service. Recycled once the call is completed.
- PerSession - Instance is created for the lifetime of a session with the client. Recycled once the session is closed (or faulted).
- Single - Instance is created on first call of the ServiceHost constructor and maintained for the lifetime of the service.

There are some extra options for changing the server instance release behaviour exposed through properties on [MSDN : ServiceBehaviorAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit:**

`ServiceHost` constructor is called when the `Open()` method is called on the client proxy class (in this case `MyServiceClient`)

Comment: Regarding InstanceContextMode.Single: 1. When does ServiceHost constructor being called - here: `MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();` or here: `client.DoStuff();` 2. What is the "lifetime of the service" when hosted on IIS? until application recycle takes place?

Comment: **1.** `ServiceHost` constructor is called when the client requests the service for the first time during the 'Open()' method call. 
**2.** Lifetime of the service is equivalent to lifetime of the IIS application - so application recycle, IIS reset or application shutdown.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about the `Open()` method! Just to add that Open() is called only when accessing the `Channel` property of the auto generated proxy (Channel property calls CreateChannelInternal(), which calls CreateChannel(), which calls base.EnsureOpened()). That's the part I was missing from the puzzle to fully understand your answer.